# Adding an element in a sublist through a list iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist, listiterator

I have an arraylist that contains elements-

```
0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700...
```

After getting a sublist out of the main list, I am adding an element if the element returned by **next()** is `400`

```
public static void add(List<String> list){
    List<String> subList = list.subList(2, 7);// 200, 300, 400, 500, 600
    ListIterator<String> listIterator = subList.listIterator();

    while(listIterator.hasNext()) {

        String value = listIterator.next();

        if(value.equals("400")) {
            listIterator.add("399");
        }

    }
    System.out.println(subList);
}
```

The sublist now becomes -

```
[200, 300, 400, 399, 500, 600]
```

As seen visible, the element `399` is **after** `400`.

The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)) says

> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). The
>   element is inserted immediately **before** the element that would be
>   returned by **next()**....

Please clarify.

Comment: Not the element that _was_ returned by next(). "The element that *would be* returned by next()" is 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by next()

It means the element will be inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by the **next** call to `next()` (i.e. the call to `next()` that takes place **after** the call to `listIterator.add("399")`, not before it), which is 500. Therefore the new element is added before 500.

Answer (score 1):

> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by next().

```
   public static void add(List<String> list){
        List<String> subList = list.subList(2, 7);// 200, 300, 400, 500, 600
        ListIterator<String> listIterator = subList.listIterator();

        while(listIterator.hasNext()) {

            String value = listIterator.next();

            if(value.equals("400")) {   //when this statement is executed next would return 400
 //399 will be inserted before next call to next() function , next call to next() function would return 500, so it will be inserted before 500*/
                listIterator.add("399");  
            }

        }
        System.out.println(subList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> immediately before the element **that would be returned by `next()`**

And the element which would be returned by `next` at that point is 500.